# Maximum Running VM's in Virtual PC 2007

Tags: virtualization, limitations, windows-virtual-pc

I'm trying to find out what is the *maximum* number of virtual machines I can run at the same time in Virtual PC 2007 but I can't seem to find this information on the Microsoft website. Does anyone know?

I will be running Virtual PC 2007 on Windows XP 64 if that makes any difference.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its all going to come down to resources, CPU, memory, disk space, etc. Assuming you are running WinXP x64, it supports up to 128GB of memory. Depending on what each VM will be doing, CPU will also be an issue. On the assumption that you are just trying to fire up a WinXP VM at minimum specs (512MB memory), you can probably run well over a hundred with the maximum memory installed in the system.

It sounds to me like you have a ton of VMs running, and are worried about hitting a limit. If that is the case, it's time to move away from VPC.

Answer (score 1):

I've had 10 running, I could probably have had more but I ran out of resources.

I was running the 10 on a QuadCore 2.5ghz with 12gigs of ram.